# почему не открывается второе модальное окно?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, frontend

это 2 разных js файла для каждого окна

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}





var modez = document.getElementById('modezl');
var YouBtn = document.getElementById("YouBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
!
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Reveal Demo</title>


</head>

<body>
  <a id="myBtn"><img src="img/low1.png"></a>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close"></span>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a id="myBtn"><img src="img/low1.png"></a>
  <div id="YouBtnl" class="modal">
    <div id="modez" class="mod" <div class="contmod">
      <span class="close"></span>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

"два разных js файла" с одинаковыми названиями глобальных переменных? Второй файл перекрывает переменные и `window.onclick` из первого.